# Stop, Invalidate and set to Nil a NSTimer When User Exits

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an application that has a NSTimer running as long as the button is being pressed. However, if the user exits out of the app (Multi-tasks) the timer continues to go. How can I invalidate it so that the time stops and is set to nil when the app is being exited. Can I disable multi-tasking? Thanks. P.S If it involves using the AppDelegate how do I get that NSTimer to be referenced in the AppDelegate, because it is created in the ViewController.h 
I have tired using:

```
#import "Some AppNameViewController.h"
```

Anyway, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You can disable multi tasking by setting [`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) to YES in your plist.
- The more elegant solution is to listen for the [`UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` in the class with the timer. When either of those notification are posted `invalidate` and `nil` your timer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use NSNotificationCenter and simply add your timer as an observer of a message that you send when the app exits. Example:

In the viewController:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self.myTimer selector:@selector(invalidate) name:@"killTheTimer" object:nil];
}
```

In the delegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"killTheTimer" object:nil];
}
```